# Scanner class in my Eclipse does not have Scanner(Path) method

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I want to give a path to scanner as an argument, I saw other versions of Eclipse that when you type Scanner and then hold control+space it'll show Scanner(Path arg0) as a suggestion, but mine doesn't have that, so I want to know how could I get that library?

Comment: There are many different classes called `Scanner` - make sure you are importing the correct one

Comment: You need to be using Java 7 (or later) to get the `Path` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` class was introduced from java 1.5 and its the part of `java.util` package, either you must be using earlier version of java, else your eclipse is wrongly configured.